# Some questions related to the energy of a viscoelastic bar

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, mathematical-physics, continuum-mechanics

Let's consider a problem of free longitudinal vibrations of an one dimensional infinitely long elastic relaxing bar (Maxwell material) with constant cross section. The bar's displacement $u$ and stress $\sigma$ satisfy the system of equations
$$
\rho \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial x}, \quad \gamma \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial t} = \beta \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial t} + \sigma,\quad (1)
$$
where $\rho > 0$ is the density of bar, $\beta > 0$ is the relaxation time of the bar, $\gamma \beta^{-1} > 0$ is the elastic modulus of the bar.

According to the continuum mechanics, energy of the bar can be expressed as

$$
E = T + \Pi,\quad T = \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{V} \rho \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)^2 dV,\quad \Pi = \frac{1}{2} \int\limits_{V} \sigma \varepsilon dV,
$$
where $T$ is the kinetic energy, $\Pi$ is the potential energy, $dV$ is a volume element, $V$ is the volume of the bar, $\varepsilon = \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ is the bar's strain.

We can write $\gamma \dot{\varepsilon} = \beta \dot{\sigma} + \sigma$ (this is an analog of Hooke's law for Maxwell material), and integrate it $\varepsilon = \dfrac{\beta \sigma}{\gamma} + \dfrac{1}{\gamma} \displaystyle \int\limits^t \sigma dt$

After calculation we get
$$
E(t) = \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \rho S \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(t,x)\right)^2 dx + \frac{1}{2} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\beta}{\gamma} S \sigma^2 (t,x)  dx + \frac{1}{2} \int\limits_{0}^{t} d\tau \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{S}{\gamma} \sigma^2 (\tau,x) dx, \quad (2)
$$
where $S$ is the bar's cross section area.

It is easy to show that the energy (2) of the system (1) does not increase.

But there is another way to derive the "energy". Multiply the first equation of system (1) by $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ and integrate over all $x$:
$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \rho \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} dx = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial x} \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} dx.
$$
Integrate by parts
$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \rho \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} dx = -\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \sigma \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t \partial x} dx.
$$
Substitute $\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t \partial x}$ from the second equation of (1)
$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \rho \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} dx + \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\gamma} \sigma \left(\beta \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial t} + \sigma\right) dx = 0.
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{1}{2} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \rho \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(t,x) \right)^2 dx + \frac{1}{2} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\beta}{\gamma} \sigma^2(t,x) dx + \int\limits_{0}^{t} d \tau \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\gamma} \sigma^2(\tau,x) dx \right)= 0.
$$

So, the quantity
$$
\widetilde{E}(t) = \frac{1}{2} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \rho \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(t,x) \right)^2 dx + \frac{1}{2} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\beta}{\gamma} \sigma^2(t,x) dx + \int\limits_{0}^{t} d \tau \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\gamma} \sigma^2(\tau,x) dx\quad\quad (3)
$$
is conserved.

But (3) is not an true energy of the bar. The value $S \widetilde{E}$ is also not the real energy of the system, but at least it is already measured in joules. We would get $S \widetilde{E}$ if we integrated over the bar's volume $V$.

We can also consider the function
$$
E_1(t) = \frac{1}{2} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \rho \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(t,x) \right)^2 dx + \frac{1}{2} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\beta}{\gamma} \sigma^2(t,x) dx,
$$
and show that it does not increase.

And with that, I have questions:

1. What is the functions $\widetilde{E}$ and $E_1$. What is their physical meaning?
2. What is physical meaning of conservation of $\widetilde{E}$. This is the law of conservation of what?
3. Is the function $E$ the energy of the bar? Or did I miscalculate?

EDIT #1: We assume that the functions $u$ and $\sigma$ are sufficiently smooth, and the functions $x \mapsto u(t,x)$ and $x \mapsto \sigma(t,x)$ for each time $t \in [0,\infty)$ have compact support.